# Servlet could not be instantiated

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to make a simple download servlet to download a jar. I have added mapping in web.xml deployment descriptor. When i try run on server i get below error.

[image]

below is my project directory and web.xml file. I am able to access the other two servlets fine i.e. `LoginServlet` and `ShoppingServlet`.

[image]

I somehow managed to fix the above servlet by creating a new class file. Now the thing is i am not able to download the jar file as it says `InputStream` is null.

[image]

Below is the source code for `DownloadServlet`.

```
package shop;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException {
        System.out.println("It reached the servlet");
        response.setContentType("application/jar");
        
        ServletContext ctx = getServletContext();
        InputStream ips = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/test.jar");
        System.out.println( "input stream is " + (ips == null ? "null" : "not null"));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        while((read=ips.read(buffer))!=-1) {
            os.write(buffer,0,read);
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        
}
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException {
        doPost(request,response);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your webapp and servlet seem ok. After all the webapp gets deployed, the servlet got instantiated and registered to the URL, you are able to invoke that URL with a POST request and the servlet tried to respond.

But then something went wrong, the servlet threw an exception and Tomcat was smart enough to present you that exception as HTML page. Did you read it?

It says that the servlet threw a NullPointerException in line 25 because 'ips' is null. Seeing that that's where you try to get an InputStream to your resource you never checked whether that path is correct or the resource behind exists.

Where did you place the file you want to offer for download? Does the file exist at the right place? Check if the access you intended to go for really works. Somehow I feel you should use a different path. Or for a beginning try to serve a file from the filesystem. Check against the documentation of [getResourceAsStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).

Comment: getResourceAsStream() finds a resource under context path. Context path is `\shop` and jar is present at `\shop\test.jar`.

Comment: It worked when i placed the jar file under /WEB-INF directory....not sure why it doesn't work for context path.